# How to prevent sortable when there is only one item

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using JQuery UI sortable ,How do i prevent the sortable action when there is only one element ?

Comment: I am using the standard jquery-ui sortable example http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/ . On page refresh the sortable event would be bound to the ul but if  i keep removing lis till i have only one left the event will still be bound .

Answer (score 1):

Check before sortable use.For example:

```
var n = $("div li").length;
 if(n>1)
 {
  $("div li" ).sortable({ items: 'li' });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of siblings that the element has, if it is equal to 0 then there is only one element so then you can call .sortable('destroy') to remove the sortable functionality.

```
if ($(this).siblings().length < 2) {
  $(this).sortable('destroy');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no option to explicitly set a minimum amount of items so there's no other way than to check manually.